# Thymeleaf передать в option список объектов

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Есть класс Equipment, у которого параметр status это объект Status.
В форме создания/редактирования Equipment мне нужно показать выпадающий список со всеми возможными Status, а в случае редактирования с выбранным текущим.

```
@Table(name = "equipments")
public class Equipment {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "serial-number")
    private String serialNumber;

    @Column(name = "brand")
    private String brand;

    @Column(name = "model")
    private String model;

    @Column(name = "type")
    private String type;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="status")
    private Status status;

    @Column(name = "purchase-date")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDate purchaseDate;

    @Column(name = "purchase-cost")
    private Long purchaseCost;

    @Column(name = "amortization-period")
    private Long amortizationPeriod;
```

Контроллеры:

```
    public String showNewEquipmentForm(Model model) {
        Equipment equipment = new Equipment();
        model.addAttribute("equipment", equipment);
        return "new_equipment";
    }
```

```
@GetMapping("/statuses")
    public String viewHomePage(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("listStatuses", statusService.getAllStatuses());
        return "statuses";
    }
```

Форма:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/equipments/saveEquipment}" th:object="${equipment}"
        method="POST">
    <input type="text" th:field="*{serialNumber}"
           placeholder="Серийный номер" class="form-control mb-4 col-4">
    <input type="text" th:field="*{brand}"
           placeholder="Бренд" class="form-control mb-4 col-4">
    <input type="text" th:field="*{model}"
           placeholder="Модель" class="form-control mb-4 col-4">
    <input type="text" th:field="*{type}"
           placeholder="Тип" class="form-control mb-4 col-4">

    <select th:field="*{status}" id="status">
      <option th:each="status : ${statuses}"
              th:value="${status.getId()}"
              th:name="${status}"
              th:text="${status.getName()}">
      </option>
    </select>

    <input type="text" th:field="*{purchaseDate}"
           placeholder="Дата закупки" class="form-control mb-4 col-4">
    <input type="text" th:field="*{purchaseCost}"
           placeholder="Стоимость закупки" class="form-control mb-4 col-4">
    <input type="text" th:field="*{amortizationPeriod}"
           placeholder="Период амортизации" class="form-control mb-4 col-4">

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info col-2">Сохранить</button>
  </form>
```

В таком варианте список пустой.
Пробовал заменить getId на id и getName на name. Также пробовал использовать атрибут listStatuses.
Список всегда пустой.

Пробовал и так:

```
    <select th:#object="${status}" id="status">
      <option th:each="status : ${listStatuses}"
              th:value="${status.id}"
              th:name="*{status}"
              th:text="${status.name}">
      </option>
    </select>
```

Comment: "Пробовал и так" - кажется, этот вариант вполне верный. Вы передаёте список `listStatuses` ровно с таким названием, и в самом Thymeleaf-представлении верно по нему проходитесь. Проверьте метод `getAllStatuses()` - вдруг он выдаёт пустой список. Также посмотрите, для той ли страницы вы выдаёте этот список. Ну и наконец, у вас явная опечатка вот в этом месте: `<select th:#object="${status}" id="status">`. Решётка лишняя.

Comment: Список у меня выдаётся для страницы просмотра статусов
`@GetMapping("/statuses")`

А в Equipment - `@GetMapping("/equipments/showNewEquipmentForm")`
Не понимаю как сделать так, чтобы контроллер статусов отдавал и на странице `/equipments/showNewEquipmentForm`

Пробовал написать новый такой же контроллер, а также в контроллер Equipment пробовал добавить `model.addAttribute("listStatuses", statusService.getAllStatuses());`

Comment: Спасибо, получилось.
Когда в контроллер Equipment пытался вызвать `getAllStatuses()` не указал что `statusService` `@Autowired `